# Removing specific part of filename (what's after the second dash) for all files in a folder

Tags: bash, rename

I use the command line utility `youtube-dl` to download videos from YouTube and make mp3s from them with `avconv`. I'm doing this under Ubuntu 14.04 and very happy with it.

The utility downloads the files and saves them with the following name scheme:

```
TITLE(artist-track)-ID.mp3
```

So an actual filename looks like:

```
EPIC RAP BATTLE of MANLINESS-_EzDRpkfaO4.mp3
```

Some other file names in the folder look like:

```
EPIC RAP BATTLE of MANLINESS-_EzDRpkfaO4.mp3
Martin Garrix - Animals (Official Video)-gCYcHz2k5x0.mp3
Stromae - Papaoutai-oiKj0Z_Xnjc.mp3
```

At first, this was no problem. It didn't bother me while listening to my music in Rhytmbox.
But when moving to phone or other devices it is pretty confusing to see a so long name, and some players, like the Samsung ones, treat that last part (id after second dash) of the name as Album or something.

I'd like to create a bash script that removes what's after the second dash in the name for all files, so it'll make them like this:

From: `Martin Garrix - Animals (Official Video)-gCYcHz2k5x0.mp3`

To: `Martin Garrix - Animals (Official Video).mp3`

Is it also possible to instruct `youtube-dl` to exclude the ID from now on?

I am currently downloading with the command:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-quality 0 --audio-format mp3 URL
```

Comment: If you don't insist on a `bash` script, Emacs' Dired mode (specifically its variant called WDired, for "Writable Dired") would help.  See here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Wdired.html . In WDired, you basically *edit* a buffer containing an `ls` output, then `C-c C-c` to *commit* those changes to the filesystem.  And you can use all Emacs goodies, in particular `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp`.  (And also write a short Elisp helper function to automate it, or record a keyboard macro and save it, and then even call it from the shell like a `bash` script!)

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. Might be useful. I was looking for a bash script for being able to run it easily under a bunch of directories.

Comment: This link: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/03/25/working-multiple-files-dired/ has some info on operating on files from multiple directories in *one* Dired buffer, so if you can `find` (as in `GNU find`) all your files, you could even run the replacing engine only once!

Comment: Solved already as in the accepted answer, I think I might use this if I need again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sed can accomplish this in a single line, albeit in a rather convoluted way.

```
ls | sed 's/\(.*\)\(-.*\)/mv \"&\" \"\1.mp3\"/' | bash
```

This first lists the files in the current directory (assuming all the files you want to rename are in the current directory), and then uses sed's s/regex/replacement command to generate a sensible mv command which is then piped to bash which executes it. This assumes all of your files are something of the form "A-C.mp3" or "A - B-C.mp3". Here is how it works:

The regex part of the sed command is

```
\(.*\)\(-.*\)
```

this "groups" the name into two groupings (delimited with escaped parentheses): one matching ".*" (any number of any character) and another matching "-.*", a dash followed by any number of any character. Notice that this matches the entire filename (in two groups). Also note that since "greedy" regex is used, the first group will match "A" in "A-C.mp3" and "A - B", not just "A ", in "A - B-C.mp3", as wanted.

The replacement part of the sed command is

```
mv \"&\" \"\1.mp3\"/
```

Note that an & character instructs sed to insert the entire pattern that matched regex, in this case that is the entire filename, and the \1 instructs sed to insert the part of the filename that matched the first grouping ".*". These two are combined with an preceding mv and a trailing .mp3, with escaped quotation marks to produce a sensible rename command. For example, for "A - B-C.mp3", the full sed command will produce:

```
mv "A - B-C.mp3" "A - B.mp3"
```

And finally all of this is piped to bash, which happily executes the mv (rename) command.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly (tried other methods and game me "--NAME-- is not a directory"). Is there any way to do this recursively? (I have tracks arranged in subdirectories of my Music folder.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this recursively by simply instructing ls to recursively list all files with their full path. Using "ls -d -1 $PWD/**/*" instead of "ls" as the first command should work, this lists all the files with their full path using the recursive globbing operator ** in all subdirectories but not the current directory, although I would recommend testing it first to see that it is sane (i.e. running the entire command without the final piping to bash). Note that bash version >= 4 is needed for support for recursive globbing.

Comment: -1, [do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 13):

I would use the Perl-based `rename` command - for example, to remove the shortest sequence of word-characters starting with `-` ahead of the `.mp3` suffix, you could try

```
rename -nv -- 's/-\w+?[.]mp3$/.mp3/' *.mp3
```

The `n` option runs the command in 'dry run' mode - if the matches appear correct, remove the `n` option and run it again.

Comment: You could just use `\.` instead of `[.]`.

Answer (score 10):

The part you don't want is the video id. You can use youtube-dl's output template functionality:

```
--output "%(title)s"
```

this will use only the title and omit the id. Run `youtube-dl` with no parameters to see other options.

You can fix your existing downloads:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" `basename "$i" .mp3 | cut -f -2 -d "-"`.mp3; done
```

(This is equivalent to Jakke's answer).

Comment: Thanks for the first command (to manipulate the output filename). I'd upvote if I could but don't have enough rep yet (I'll come back and upvote when I'll have). Not gave it accepted answer because the second command threw up "--NAME-- is not a directory" for every track. For fixing already downloaded @icasdri's answer worked. Again, thanks for the youtube-dl argument thingie.

Comment: Coming back to correct something, I need to change "%(title)s" to "%(title)s.%(ext)s" because it was complaining about audio and video having the same name and not being able to convert. Cheers!

Comment: Safer version: `mv -- "$i" "$(basename "$i" .mp3 | cut -f 2 -d "-")".mp3`.

Answer (score 4):

You can check it with this command:

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo "$(echo $i|cut -d- -f1,2).mp3"; done
```

Note that you do have file names without 2 dashes, so it won't work for everything.

If you actually want to change the names,

```
for i in *.mp3
do
  newname="$(echo $i|cut -d- -f1,2).mp3";
  mv $i $newname
done
```

Comment: If you want to play it safe, do a cp instead of a mv. It will leave you with the original files, but you'll probably have to remove them manually later

Comment: You should edit your comment about `cp` vs `mv` into your answer

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'll new it is 4 spaces... just have a problem counting sometimes :D

Comment: -1, [do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: You should also double quote every variable expansion and command substitution. And don't use `echo` for anything other than plain text, it's unportable.

Comment: @nyuszika7h This answer does *not* parse any `ls` output.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju That's because it was edited by someone since then. Check the revision history: https://askubuntu.com/posts/481848/revisions

Answer (score 0):

A solution using only the shell:

```
filename=foo-bar-baz

while read -rd-; do
    newname="${newname:+$newname-}$REPLY"
done <<< "$filename"

mv "$filename" "$newname"
```

This works because the file name doesn't end with a dash, so the last token is ignored.